# Minimal Tree for Selected Points on a Directed Grid

Tags: tree, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, directed-graph, approximation

The goal is to find the minimal tree connecting selected points to a target point on a directed grid. The tree is minimal in the total number of points it contains, and it's assumed each point costs the same (no weights).

For example, take a look on the following grid:

```
o -> + -> o -> *
^    ^    ^    ^
|    |    |    |
o -> + -> o -> +
^    ^    ^    ^
|    |    |    |
o -> + -> o -> o
^    ^    ^    ^
|    |    |    |
o -> o -> o -> o
```

The goal is to find the minimal tree from the points marked in "+" to the target point *. 
The solution in this case is:

```
o -> W -> W -> *
^    ^    ^    ^
|    |    |    |
o -> W -> o -> W
^    ^    ^    ^
|    |    |    |
o -> W -> o -> o
^    ^    ^    ^
|    |    |    |
o -> o -> o -> o
```

Im aware that this problem might be NP-hard, since it sounds to me as some variation of Steiner tree.

Im looking for an algorithm (and code if possible) that solves this. Both solutions for small grid/number of points and approximations to the optimal tree are welcome.

**Edit:** unclear how to use minimum spanning tree in this case. Let's look on the following example:

```
+ -> o -> o -> o -> o -> *
^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^
|    |    |    |    |    |
o -> o -> + -> o -> o -> o
^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^
|    |    |    |    |    |
o -> o -> o -> o -> o -> o
```

The graph contains just the selected points and target point as nodes will have:
one edge from the left point to target
4 edges for the right point to target
All trees in this graph will be MST but only the one is the solution in the original grid. It will be the one which on the original grid have the paths for the two points collides the most.

I can find all the MSTs and then choose the one where there is minimum unique points in the original grid. Not sure if thats always the right solution and how complex its running time is.

Comment: What have you tried and what is your question?

Comment: Im looking mainly for the right algorithm. didn't implemented a solution yet since Im not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

OK - this is wrong because the tree it constructs has branches only at wanted points and you can do better by making branches at other points, as your example shows.

I think every candidate tree contains selected points, a target point, and unwanted points. I think you could count the total number of points by counting edges, because a tree on N points has N-1 edges. So I think you can minimize the number of unwanted points by finding the candidate tree with fewest edges, and I think this is the minimum spanning tree problem, as described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree.

Comment: It is unclear how to use it - I edited with an example.

Comment: Thanks for this correction - I now think that you are right that this is the Steiner tree problem. In fact it looks a lot like what Wikipedia describes as the metric Steiner tree problem. I have edited my answer to explain why it is wrong.